# ¿Como retornar sólo el campo de una colección en Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo este simple código que me funciona a la perfección:

```
firestore () {
  return {
    items: db.collection('items')
  }
},
```

El problema es que mi app renderiza items en forma de array, con lo cual el hecho de retornar un objeto me hace imprimir el "name":"valor_que_quiero_retornar".

Ejemplo:

```js
  items = [  { "name": "tarea numero 1" }
{ "name": "tarea numero 2" }
{ "name": "tarea numero 3" }
{ "name": "tarea numero 4" } ]
```

Como puedo especificar a Firestore que solo quiero que me devuelva el field de "name" y no el objeto entero? Para que así mi app solo renderize:

```js
 items = ["tarea numero 1","tarea numero 2","tarea numero","tarea numero 4" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que en firestore no puedes obtener documentos parciales, o sea que fierestore siempre te regresará los objetos completos, así que la solución es filtrar en tu código los campos que necesitas.

Si estas usando javascript puedes usar la función map para transformarlo a como lo necesitas:

...

```
var nombres = items.map(function(objeto) {
    return objeto.name;
});
console.log(nombres)  // ["tarea numero 1", "tarea numero 2", "tarea numero 3", "tarea numero 4"]
```